# Does Amazon Mechanical Turk support dynamical content adjustment in HIT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I need to use AMT HIT to resolve a number of questions. However, there is some dependency in my questions. For example, if they select A with Yes choice,  we will direct them to question C otherwise, we direct them to question B. The problem is: with AMT's web batch management, this seems not possible. 
In this case, putting question B on the HIT (if A is selected Yes) will incur additional monetary cost.

So if we can dynamically change the content of the HIT, then we can first show question A, then when A is selected Yes, we can show the next question as C and skip question B to save money.

Does Amazon Mechanical Turk support dynamically changing the content in a single HIT?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use javascript in a HIT created in the requester user interface or in an HTMLQuestion HIT created via the API. If you use an ExternalQuestion to host a HIT on your own website, you can of course use server- or client-side technology to create dynamic elements. The "default" QuestionForm HIT structure does not support dynamic elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does AMT "default" QuestionForm  support getting the overall error ratio of the worker? Here I mean obtaining the historical error ratio of the worker instead of the error ratio for the QuestionForm I have posted.

Comment: You cannot really get information about workers of that kind. You could query workers' previous performance on your HITs (but you would need a server-side application that would dynamically query the API for that). You can use QualificationRequirements to restrict a HITType to workers with particular performance levels (>90% approved HITs) but you can't obtain worker-specific scores on those metrics.

Comment: I searched on the web and found a method that can roughly do this task by adding some golden standard HITs, i.e., the tasks that we know answer. Then we can check the error ratio in the golden standard HITs and get an estimation of worker's error ratio.

Comment: Sorry that I do not have enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: Yes, you can use an Assignment-level ReviewPolicy that includes so-called "known answers". If workers get "known answers" wrong, then that can tell you things about their performance in general. You'll need to use the API to create a ReviewPolicy.